# How to add "authorization" check to selective API's in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a react+node based project where I build all my react based components in a `dist/` directory and then upload this directory to the server and serve it via nodeJS `express.static()` method.

> server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))

I have also written a node middleware which captures every request and checks if auth token is passed to it or not.

```
users.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({message : err})
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({message : 'Please send a token'})
    }
})
```

But the issue that now I am facing is that, when I run URL such as `http://localhost:3001/dashboard`, the node middleware also captures it and check for token instead of rendering my webview.

How do I differentiate between webview requests and other server requests in nodeJS

Answer (score 5):

If you need to check auth for only some specific API you can do in following 3 ways:

1. Write all the functions(API) that don't use auth above/before your auth check function

`

```
users.get('/yourAPI1', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.get('/yourAPI2', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.get('/yourAPI3', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({message : err})
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({message : 'Please send a token'})
    }
});

//Now those functions which need auth checks
users.post('/yourAPI4', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.post('/yourAPI5', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});
```

`

2. Modify your Auth function to skip all `GET` API. **NOTE: Use this only if you use `GET` to load HTML page and not to fetch data like search of any other info.**

`

```
users.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //Just a check for `GET` API
    if(req.method === 'GET') {return next();}

    const token = req.headers.authorization
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({message : err})
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({message : 'Please send a token'})
    }
});
```

`

3. Call Auth function from only those API which needs to check auth like:

`

```
function checkAuth (req, res, next) {

    const token = req.headers.authorization
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({message : err})
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({message : 'Please send a token'})
    }
});

//Escaping auth check
users.get('/yourAPI6', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

//Need auth for this
users.get('/yourAPI7', checkAuth, function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.post('/yourAPI8', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.post('/yourAPI9', checkAuth function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.put('/yourAPI10', function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});

users.put('/yourAPI11', checkAuth function(req, res, next) {
    //Do your stuff
});
```

`

Out of all these I will prefer 3rd one as It gives you flexibility to use as a function and anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a redirection for all your routes to point to your `index.html` or whatever is your start page.

```
/*  route to static files */
server.use('/static-route-here', express.static(__dirname + '/static-folder-here'))

/* multiple definitions of other server routes */
server.get('api/*', authMiddleWare ,(req, res) => {
  /*do api stuff here*/
})

/* anything else is redirected to index.html */
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

Comment: do I have to give static path ..... `server.use('/static-route-here`...

Comment: Yes, also ideally the route of your api should be different than route of your website, I'd recommend adding a parent route for all APIs.

Comment: how can i do that (adding parent route for all api's) ?

Comment: @DeanAmbrose, keep all your apis under an /api route